# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - php 5.5 not working

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.5

I moved from one server (php 4.5) to a new server (php 5.5)
and the attach script is not running (means not writing to the DB) :

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_real_connect($db, 'localhost', 'user', 'pass','db_name');

mysqli_select_db($db, 'db_name');

$insert_data= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'http://123.co.il/file/some_file.csv'
INTO TABLE guests
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";

mysqli_query($db,$insert_data);
?>
```

please, some help?
Thanks,
Mor

Comment: My guess:  you are either not connected to the database you think you are or the table `guests` doesn't exist in it.

Comment: there is no error connection . and the same script worked perfectly in the old server (php 4.5) . any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you are on localhost?Also you dont need mysqli_select_db if you specify the dbname in the connection

Comment: Hi Mihai , Yes i'm sure :\

Comment: maybe there is other script for php 5.5?

Comment: Is the name of both your DB same('db_name') ? Else specify.

Comment: Hi @usermesam0023, and yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the solution is: replace the path from the url , direct to the file: 
'http://123.co.il/file/some_file.csv'  - >  'some_file.csv'

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_init();
mysqli_real_connect($db, 'localhost', 'user', 'pass','db_name');

mysqli_select_db($db, 'db_name');

$insert_data= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'some_file.csv'
INTO TABLE guests
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';";

mysqli_query($db,$insert_data);
?>
```

hope it will help to others.
Mor